# duplicated markers when calling a function using setinterval google maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markers

I have the next code to retrieve some data from a xml file. The problem is that when I want to refresh the markers, the response that I get is a duplicated marker in the map. How can I update the points without having duplicated markers?

Best regards

```
//<![CDATA[
  // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the       side_bar 
  var side_bar_html = ""; 

  // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
  // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
  var gmarkers = []; 

 // global "map" variable
  var map = null;
  var markerclusterer = null;

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 



function createMarker(latlng, imei, html, estado, alias, speed, timestamp) {
if(estado == 1)
  image = '/artworks/icons/truck_green3.png';
else
  image = '/artworks/icons/truck_red.png';
var textoLabel= "this is the text"
var contentString = html;
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: latlng,
    icon: image,
    // map: map,
    labelContent: textoLabel,
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.50},
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
// save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
gmarkers.push(marker);
// add a line to the side_bar html
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + imei + '<\/a><br>';
}

    // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}



function initialize() {
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.169619,-3.756981),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);
}
    function getMarkers() {
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });
  // Read the data from example.xml
  downloadUrl("vehiculos.asp", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var imei = markers[i].getAttribute("imei");
      var alias = markers[i].getAttribute("alias");
      var speed= markers[i].getAttribute("speed");
      var timestamp= markers[i].getAttribute("timestamp");
      var estado= markers[i].getAttribute("estado");
      var conectado= markers[i].getAttribute("conectado");
var html="<b>"+alias+"</b><br> a una velocidad de "+speed+" km/h <br/>     ultima posicion  a las: "+timestamp;

      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,alias+" "+imei,html,estado, speed, timestamp );
    }

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
    // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  });
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
 });

  // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array.
  function clearOverlays() {
    getMarkers(null);
  }

  // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
  function deleteOverlays() {
    clearOverlays();
    getMarkers = [];
  }
setInterval(clearOverlays, 3000);
setInterval(deleteOverlays, 4000);
setInterval(getMarkers, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your markers unique ids (maybe one of your existing attributes is already unique).  If the unique id already exists, move that marker to the new location (or just don't add it again),if it doesn't, create a new marker.

If they don't move, you can also avoid duplicates by checking the distance between new markers and all your existing markers, if it is less than a "same marker" threshold (say ~0.1 meters), don't add it again.

There is a problem with your clearOverlays method (getMarkers(null) just calls getMarkers):

```
// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++)
  {
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: And how I do that? Sorry but I m a bit new in this. About the setInterval I typed like that because I wanted to see if they were working properly. I will clear them every five seconds, at the same time.

Comment: To answer that you need to provide more details: 1. Do your markers already have unique ids? 2. Do they move?  3. And please remove any extraneous stuff from your posted code, it confuses matters.

Comment: everything marker has its own id (imei number). they move because are trucks that are moving all the time.

Comment: Probably you want to move the existing markers (trucks), rather than deleting and redrawing them.  Will the markers always exist or will they come and go (so you need to move some, delete some, add some each time you get a new data set)?  This sounds suspiciously like fleet management or tracking, have you verified that you comply with the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial)

Comment: morning!. yes I have already read it. no problem with that. So, how can I achieve that the script works as you say? could you code it?

Comment: Yes I can code it.  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and where are you running into trouble?

Comment: the main problem is that markers are repeated every time that setinterval starts, so every time I have a 17 new markers. thank you very much geocodezip for your help.

Comment: I m stucked right now, but previously I tried to split some parts of the code and put them into functions to call them separately using setinterval, but still getting same result, markers repeated...

Comment: The way to solve your immediate problem is to fix your clearOverlays method to remove all the markers from the map before clearing the array.  But you are probably going to want to move them rather than delete and recreate them.

Comment: so, can you help me with the code for moving the markers when each one get a new position?

Comment: Sure.  Where is your code that attempts to do what I have described above?

Comment: did you see how to do it then?

Comment: I know how to do it.  I have access to those files.  I don't have time right now to write your code for you and I don't see any value in doing so, any example I create will depend on your data, which will probably go away as soon as you get it working.  I am willing to help you if you make an attempt and run into problems.

Comment: hi there geocodezip, I'm working in the code, trying to delete and then set a new position to the marker, but it still repeat the data... i m working in the file that I posted before. i would like to get your help.

Comment: the markers are moving now, but the infowindows are always the first ones that appeared. I will find out how to update them at the same time the marker is moving.