# loading new markers and delete old marker. [duplicating]

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps

How to remove the old marker with time interval and replace it with new marker automatically. I'm creating a real tracker using google map. `

```
var markersArray = [];

function initialize() {

 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39, -86);
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
   zoom: 1,
   center: myLatlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'real.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
                //data: "",                       
                dataType: 'json',                //data format      
                success: function(data){          //on recieve of reply                          


var locations = data;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
deleteOverlays();
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
 markersArray.push(marker);


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}


                } 
            });
        }, 1000);

    });
 });
}
initialize();
```

How can I delete the markers I've used the clearOverlays but no markers are shown in the map. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicated markers when calling a function using setinterval google maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054782/duplicated-markers-when-calling-a-function-using-setinterval-google-maps-v3)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a marker, you need to set its map to null:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < markers.length; ii++) {
  markers[ii].setMap(null);
}
```

Or, depending on your scenario, you could just update the marker's location:

```
marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
```